# Meta humor ala xkcd

Tags: discussion

Just because.

[image: I'm the geek you don't want on meta :P]

I'm the geek you don't want on meta :P

Comment: this is exactly what meta is for :)

Comment: Chat would have one-boxed it so that you can see the hover text.  Just sayin'...

Comment: @JonEricson good to know!